# I have tried to correct this Django Object set error but it has failed

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models


class Gallery(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Gallery_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title + '_' + self.Gallery_logo


class Picture (models.Model):
    Gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Price = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Gallery' object has no attribute 'pic_set'
```

I am using Pycharm 2016 and I just began self learning Django yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have just started to learn django , let me point out that field names should begin with a lower case letter. (It's not an error to use upper case but it's confusing and not the standard)

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    gallery_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title + '_' + self.Gallery_logo


class Picture (models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Now when you define the foreign key relationship as above. Each Gallery instead has a `picture_set` that name come from the model name you have chosen which in this case is `Picture`